# Typescript, Enum, Object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this enum:

```
export enum Status {
  SemLogin,
  Valido,
  Invalido,
  Expirado
}
```

I wish that each status return an object, like this:

```
{ key: Status.Expirado.key,  icon: 'ban', color: 'danger' }
```

**Edit:**

The idea is to store one value on DB(could be the index or even its text) and retrieve an object with icon, color and some title value. So, I would have a list of status:

```
  {key: Status.SemLogin.key, icon: 'sign-out-alt', color: 'disabled'},
  {key: Status.Valido.key, icon: 'check-circle', color: 'success'},
  {key: Status.Invalido.key, icon: 'exclamation-circle', color: 'warning'},
  {key: Status.Expirado.key, icon: 'ban', color: 'danger'}
```

Then for each different status it would give me an object to show the different status.

What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: What do you expect `Status.Expirado.key` to be?

Comment: Well, could be an index or its text.
The idea is to "link" the items of the enum, to a corresponding object.
So, I give the enum stored item(index or text value) and get the corresponding object, to use in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you want the string names `Valido` or `Expirado` etc, you would just make the enum strings equal to the name:

```
export enum Status {
  SemLogin = "SemLogin",
  Valido = "Valido",
  Invalido = "Invalido",
  Expirado = "Expirado"
}
```

then just using `Status.Expirado` will be the string `Expirado`.

---

If you don't like this repetition then numeric enums have a reverse lookup that exists at runtime, so you can **alternatively** do this:

```
enum Status {
  // THIS IS NOT STRING ENUM ANY MORE
  SemLogin,
  Valido,
  Invalido,
  Expirado
}
console.log(Status[Status.Expirado])
```

[This logs `Expirado`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4UwOwVwW2BlALgQ0VAzsA3gWAFCijxgwAyA9gOYCWEANPoSAGrIA21AJuQwUwJIQAbuy49GTAKIAPAA7UATsm4SQAX1XAAxuQjpybMADo2VABRJUGANqW06IzPlLuAXQCUQA)
so it still has some repetition and doesn't have the nice behaviour that typescript still enforces enum behaviour that the first solution does.

Comment: "alternatively you can do this: `code for numeric enum`" I think I did explain that you do one or the other in my answer, not clear enough for you?

Comment: @VLAZ does the added emphasis help? :P